# Duplicating row, when joining 3 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, orm, left-join, query-builder

I wanted to join 3 tables with a common id, however I keep getting duplicated row as seen below.

[image]

I wanted each row to have only one value per type.
For example, flight, there should be only one value for either 'oneway_flight', 'roundout_flight', or 'roundin_flight', and the two remaining columns should be NULL.

Here's the desired output sample

[image]

Here's my query in SQL

```
SELECT o."flight" AS "oneway_flight", 
"ro"."flight" AS "roundout_flight", 
"ri"."flight" AS "roundin_flight", 
o.departure_time AS "oneway_departure_time", 
ro.departure_time AS "roundout_departure_time",    
ri.departure_time AS "roundin_departure_time", 
o.arrival_time AS "oneway_arrival_time", 
ro.arrival_time AS "roundout_arrival_time", 
ri.arrival_time AS "roundin_arrival_time" 
FROM "dbo"."data" "d" 
LEFT JOIN "dbo"."ONEWAY_OUTBOUND" "o" ON d.product_id = o.product_id 
LEFT JOIN "dbo"."ROUNDTRIP_OUTBOUND" "ro" ON d.product_id = ro.product_id 
LEFT JOIN "dbo"."ROUNDTRIP_INBOUND" "ri" ON d.product_id = ri.product_id 
WHERE d.product_id = 'TXXXXXXX'
```

Please let me know how I can modified the query above to achieved the desired output (shown in the second screenshot).

And please let me know if anything is unclear.

Appreciate all your helps!

Comment: Too much sample data, and can't read that tiny image text. Most people here want sample data and expected result as formatted, not images. Also take a look at [mcve] - make it easy to assist you!

Comment: Please do not edit questions to invalidate reasonable answers. Ask a new question instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need three separate queries, concatenated together.

```
SELECT o."flight" AS "oneway_flight", 
       NULL AS "roundout_flight", 
       NULL."flight" AS "roundin_flight", 
       o.departure_time AS "oneway_departure_time", 
       NULL AS "roundout_departure_time",    
       NULL AS "roundin_departure_time", 
       o.arrival_time AS "oneway_arrival_time", 
       NULL AS "roundout_arrival_time", 
       NULL AS "roundin_arrival_time" 
  FROM "dbo"."data" "d" 
  LEFT JOIN "dbo"."ONEWAY_OUTBOUND" "o" ON d.product_id = o.product_id 
  WHERE d.product_id = 'TXXXXXXX'

 UNION ALL

     SELECT NULL AS "oneway_flight", 
       "ro"."flight" AS "roundout_flight", 
       NULL AS "roundin_flight", 
       NULL AS "oneway_departure_time", 
       ro.departure_time AS "roundout_departure_time",    
       NULL AS "roundin_departure_time", 
       NULL AS "oneway_arrival_time", 
       ro.arrival_time AS "roundout_arrival_time", 
       NULL AS "roundin_arrival_time" 
  FROM "dbo"."data" "d" 
  LEFT JOIN "dbo"."ROUNDTRIP_OUTBOUND" "ro" ON d.product_id = ro.product_id 
  WHERE d.product_id = 'TXXXXXXX'

 UNION ALL

 SELECT NULL AS "oneway_flight", 
       NULL AS "roundout_flight", 
       "ri"."flight" AS "roundin_flight", 
       NULL AS "oneway_departure_time", 
       NULL AS "roundout_departure_time",    
       ri.departure_time AS "roundin_departure_time", 
       NULL AS "oneway_arrival_time", 
       NULL AS "roundout_arrival_time", 
       ri.arrival_time AS "roundin_arrival_time" 
  FROM "dbo"."data" "d" 
  LEFT JOIN "dbo"."ROUNDTRIP_INBOUND" "ri" ON d.product_id = ri.product_id 
  WHERE d.product_id = 'TXXXXXXX'
```

Comment: @Markco thank you so muchh! this works like magic. However, I wonder why the first row values are all NULL?

Comment: And one more question, I planned to use this with query builder, but it seems that union query is not supported... is there any alternatives? Thanks alot

Comment: Maybe there are no records in ONEWAY_OUTBOUND? I don't know anything about query builder, I always write my queries "by hand".

Comment: @gn2463 Ask a new (specific researched non-duplicate) question in a new post. Don't ask in comments.